# How do I get user input (int) to sum

Tags: python, integer, sum

I was working on an assignment, and I wasn't quite too sure how I would go about adding the input values from a user, assuming that they were all integers. I attempted to do this with a while loop, but it isn't working out. Is there a better way I can approach this? Thanks

```
number = 10
guessed = False
Sum = 0
while guessed == False:
    userInput= int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
    value = userInput + Sum
print(value)
```

Comment: A while loop is part of a valid strategy for solving this problem. Post your code and you'll be helped.

Comment: @RafaelBarros number = 10
guessed = False
Sum = 0
while guessed == False:
    userInput= int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
    value = userInput + Sum
    print(value)

Comment: @mhawke are you able to see it, i made an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want something that looks like this:

```
number = 10
total_sum = int()
guess = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
while guess != number:
    total_sum += guess
    if total_sum == number:
        print("Your have guessed the number {}!".format(number))
        break
    elif total_sum > number:
        print("Your sum of guesses, {}, exceeds the "\
              "number {}!".format(total_sum, number))
        break
    guess = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
```

Comment: I was trying to make a program where a user would need to guess a number, and their input would be summed until it gets to that value or higher. If it matches it exactly, it would output you got it right, if its too high then it would ask the user to play again

Comment: Got it. Fixed above. @UmerMuhammad

Answer (score -1):

if you want to add numbers check if they all are integers, if not convert them to int.
Otherwise your all inputs will be concatenated.